# Is it true that $0$ is the only exact $0$-form

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

I am totally new to the concepts of forms so sorry if my question is trivial. I came across a statement that ''there are no exact $0$-forms  as there is no $-1$ form.

So I revisited the definition of an exact form:
A form $\omega\in\Omega^{p}(M)$ is exact if there exists a form $\theta \in\Omega^{p-1}(M)$ such that $\omega=d\theta$

In particular, $p=0$ and the above definition confirms the statement, so the degree of any form is a non-negative integer?

On the other hand in one book I read that ''there are no other exact forms that $0$'' How is this possible?

Thank you for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we're talking about vector spaces (or modules or vector bundles or whatever) rather than sets, then if it's meaningful to utter the phrase "$-1$ form", then we *should* be saying that the space of $-1$ forms is the zero vector space, rather than saying it is the empty set. In particular, it does have a vector: the zero vector.

Comment: thank you Hurkyl, but how would you write this formally: i. e if now $0\in \Omega^{0}(M)$  is exact then $\exists \theta\in \Omega^{?}(M)$ (what degree)? such that $0=d\theta$?